# What is the bio-hazard with an eye symbol on Moody's pocket watch?

Tags: harry-potter, object-identification

In the film version of *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* we see Moody with a pocket watch that he uses several times.

[image: Close up of the pocket watch in question]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

It has a bio-hazard like symbol with an eye in the middle and a sort of shading in the background. **What is this?**

There are also runes around the outside but I'd imagine these are just numbers considering their placement.

Comment: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-ebb382f092d865a0c4aca15973567e29.webp

Comment: The runes are simply Norse runic numbers

Comment: Is it Moody's clock or one of Crouch junior? This could affect the interpretation of the symbols ... If I should guess, the similarity with the "biohazard" is intended but extended to "magical hazard". One "all seeing" eye (like Moody's own eye) and maybe 6 teeth, or 3 slim moons?

Comment: @Allerleirauh It isn't clear but he does use it in view of other characters so one could argue it was Moody's. However, we should "interpret" what it is as a last resort and instead try and find out what it actually is.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Differenzes between clock, moons and symbol for biohazard]

An **eye** in the middle of a symbol is in almost cases referred by as "all seeing eye". This is a symbol of early Christian, to show the eye of God, watching over humanity (Wikipedia ["Eye of Providence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_of_Providence)")

If I assume the background are **three moons** with points of intersection (see the picture), then this three are the symbol of "Triple Crescent Moon". Like this [website](https://www.ancient-symbols.com/symbols-directory/triple-crescent-moon.html) wrote: a symbol for three stages of women life, or in general three fates (birth, life and death). And it should be the opposite to the horned god.

Strange thing: If one search for pictures with "symbol triple crescent moons" one gets some of biohazard as jewelry too...

Like I wrote in my comment: The three outer circles in biohazard symbol do touch, but have no point of intersection. The symbol on Moody's clock clearly have outer circles with point of intersection.

*So it is not the biohazard symbol, but the similarity is intended I assume*, to illustrate the role of Moody as an Auror, who watch over the "normal" people (magic and non magic) to find the evil and guard them against it. "Magic-hazard", if you want to call it that.

Comment: Except it doesn't look like the Triple Crescent Moon really and is pretty much identical to the biohazard symbol.

Comment: If you assume the bows behind the eye are three long instead of six short ones, the triple crescent moons comes as close as one could come. Maybe there is an in-universe answer too. I am curious about it :) But I assume some movie-guy want to make a fancy symbol...

Comment: Except they aren't 3 long ones and clearly 6 short ones. And even if they are 3 long ones they are clearly not crescent moon shaped but rather more of a "w" shape with a dip in the middle. (And FWIW it probably is just a fancy symbol for a prop but it does get a few close ups so maybe it is meant to be something else in universe.)

Comment: I have compared the symbols again: It is not the biohazard symbol. The three outer circle parts of the biohazard symbol are touch each other, but do not overlap. In the clock's picture, the three circle parts overlap clearly. In biohazar's symbol a fourth full circle is painted with the middle of the whole symbol is the middle of the full circle. One can assume, this is replaced by the eye, but then the points of intersection/touching points of the three partial circles should not be visible...

Answer (score 2):

The symbol is a variation of the horns of Odin symbol (Odin the Norse god from Norse mythology).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Is there any evidence that this was deliberately intended to be a reference to the Horns of Odin symbol?

Comment: The use of Norse runes might corroborate this. Plus Odin had only one eye like Moody.

Comment: This fits better than "my moons"! Symbol PLUS fitting into the runes

Comment: This is old, sorry if I shouldn't be adding, but I thought it would be useful to note that on top of being a one-eyed god who brought runes to the world, Odin is often called "the mad one". Wotan, one of his names, is sometimes said translated as "fury", "frenzy" or "madness". Berserkers were also described as "Odin's special warriors".
And when "Mad" Eye moody enters, Ron says "he's supposed to be mad as a hatter these days". Plus, there's the theory that There is a theory that Óðr (sometimes called god of madness) was initially merged with Odin. So yeah, I think thematically, it fits.

Answer (score 1):

This symbols appears on a pocket watch, and pocket watches were traditionally personalized items.  They were traditional signs of status, and even simple ones were often engraved with the owner's monogram on the case.  British lords could have them further customized with their family crests or escutcheons on the case or the dial.

Based on these real-world background facts, I assumed that the symbol was Mad-Eye Moody's personal emblem.  It is thematically appropriate, with an eye appearing in a (close approximation of a) biohazard symbol—metaphorically indicating that his "mad" eye is dangerous on its own.  It is also vaguely suggestive of the masonic eye emblems that masonic lodge members sometimes incorporated into their personal crests.

Answer (score 0):

It's a reference to Mad-Eye Moody's actor [Brendan Gleeson's role](https://movies.fandom.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Goblet_of_Fire) as [Frank in 28 Days Later](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/28_Days_Later), a popular zombie flick from 2002. In addition, it features Norse runes for the 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, and 11.

Comment: Is he known as a master of runes? He was an Auror.

Comment: Apparently there's no evidence to support that Aurors take Ancient Runes. I've removed that claim.

Comment: In what way is it a reference? Can you offer any evidence to back up this claim?